# HighCharts: 2 Axis all same values looks weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am currently working with the current version of HighCharts and have the problem, that I have a graph with 2 Axis (1 column and 1 spline) but the values for each data point are exactly the same:

I created a JSFiddle for the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/p8y5bqd3/

The source code is here, too:

```
/*** Experimental Highcharts plugin to implement chart.alignThreshold option. This primary axis will be computed first, then all following axes will be aligned to the threshold.Author: Torstein Hønsi Last revision: 2016-11-02 */
(function (H) {
var Axis = H.Axis,
    inArray = H.inArray,
    wrap = H.wrap;

wrap(Axis.prototype, 'adjustTickAmount', function (proceed) {
    var chart = this.chart,
        primaryAxis = chart[this.coll][0],
        primaryThreshold,
        primaryIndex,
        index,
        newTickPos,
        threshold;

    // Find the index and return boolean result
    function isAligned(axis) {
        index = inArray(threshold, axis.tickPositions); // used in while-loop
        return axis.tickPositions.length === axis.tickAmount && index === primaryIndex;
    }

    if (chart.options.chart.alignThresholds && this !== primaryAxis) {
        primaryThreshold = (primaryAxis.series[0] && primaryAxis.series[0].options.threshold) || 0;
        threshold = (this.series[0] && this.series[0].options.threshold) || 0;

        primaryIndex = primaryAxis.tickPositions && inArray(primaryThreshold, primaryAxis.tickPositions);

        if (this.tickPositions && this.tickPositions.length &&
                primaryIndex > 0 &&
                primaryIndex < primaryAxis.tickPositions.length - 1 &&
                this.tickAmount) {

            // Add tick positions to the top or bottom in order to align the threshold
            // to the primary axis threshold
            while (!isAligned(this)) {

                if (index < primaryIndex) {
                    newTickPos = this.tickPositions[0] - this.tickInterval;
                    this.tickPositions.unshift(newTickPos);
                    this.min = newTickPos;
                } else {
                    newTickPos = this.tickPositions[this.tickPositions.length - 1] + this.tickInterval;
                    this.tickPositions.push(newTickPos);
                    this.max = newTickPos;
                }
                proceed.call(this);
            }
        }

    } else {
        proceed.call(this);
    }
});
}(Highcharts));

 Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    alignThresholds: true,
    type: 'area'
},
title: {
    text: 'The <em>alignThreshold</em> option is true'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},
yAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: 'Primary Axis'
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0
}, {
    title: {
        text: 'Secondary Axis'
    },
    opposite: true
}],
series: [{
type : 'column',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    yAxis: 0,
    pointWidth: 20,

}, {
type : 'spline',
    data: [5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000],
    yAxis: 1
}]
});
```

If I use a area (or column, ...) graph for the second axis, everything works fine. The problem only occurs with a spline or a line graph.

The perfect solution should somehow look like in this picture (the first data point should of course be on the same level as all the others, but still over the 0 point of the 1 axis)
[image]

Is there any way to define an offset for the spline or line graph so that the line does not start at 0 on the secondary axis?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your goal - but how about defining axis min/max? http://jsfiddle.net/p8y5bqd3/4/

Comment: Thanks! That works. Sometimes it can be so simple :)